# Computed property not working when using `Object.values()`

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity, urql

I'm using the urql GraphQL-Client to run a bunch of queries in a component. I want to create a `loading` computed prop indicating if any of these queries are running. To be able to easily compute this, I wrapped the queries in an object:

```js
const gql = {
  queryA: doQueryA(),
  queryB: doQueryB(),
  queryC: doQueryC()
};
```

which should allow me to compute the loading state like:

```js
// does not work
const loading = computed(() => Object.values(gql).some(query => query.fetching));
```

however, this does not update once all queries are done. Doing it explicitly works:

```js
// works
const loading = computed(() =>
  gql.queryA.fetching ||
  gql.queryB.fetching ||
  gql.queryC.fetching
);
```

which made me think that since `.some` can return early, maybe that's a problem for Vues reactivity tracking. So I tried to force it to access every query every time:

```js
// does not work
const loading = computed(() => Object.values(gql)
  .map(query => query.fetching)
  .some(isFetching => isFetching));
```

However, that does not help either.

Can somebody explain why this problem exists?

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet and words are form Vue documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-caching-vs-methods)

> Consider,
>
> ```
> const author = reactive({
>  name: 'John Doe',
>  books: [
>    'Vue 2 - Advanced Guide',
>    'Vue 3 - Basic Guide',
>    'Vue 4 - The Mystery'
>  ]
> })
> ```
>
> ```js
> // in component
> function calculateBooksMessage() {
>   return author.books.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
> }
> ```
>
> A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed. This means as long as `author.books` has not changed, multiple access to publishedBooksMessage will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the getter function again.
>
> This also means the following computed property will never update, because `Date.now()` is not a reactive dependency:
>
> ```js
> const now = computed(() => Date.now())
> ```

So, for your question, since gql is not a reactive property, it does not fire update for the computed property.

Comment: I understand the reactivity fundamentals. Mostly, at least. I'm fairly sure that the `fetching` property is reactive. Otherwise, how could the more explicit approach I showed work? And I do access `fetching` directly - after having gotten the parent object out of the `values()` array. If this wasn't working at all, I'd suspect a basic reactivity issue. But it's only not working when I access it in a particular way, which I find confusing

Answer (score 0):

Urql's `.fetching` is a `ref<boolean>`. That means that the code needs to be adjusted to

```js
const loading = computed(() => Object.values(gql)
  .map(query => query.fetching)
  .some(isFetching => isFetching.value)); // add .value access
```

otherwise the reference that is `isFetching` will always be truthy.

Then how did the other example work? Well, it all comes down to the fact that `"" || 7` is not `true` but `7`. So `ref(false) || ref(true)` will just be `ref(false)`. Effectively, my `loading` property was just tracking the first of all the queries, which gave the impression that it was at least doing *something*. Not the right thing, though.